# Physical significance of omitting a purely time dependent term from a Lagrangian

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, action, equations-of-motion

For a simple pendulum whose point of support moves on a vertical circle of radius $a$ with constant frequency $\gamma$, you can write the Lagrangian down. The potential energy can be written as $-mg(-a \sin \gamma t + \ell \cos \phi)$, where $\ell$ is the length of the pendulum rod and $\phi$ is the angle made by the pendulum rod with the vertical.

I understand that since the first term in the potential depends only on time, it may be omitted when incorporating it into the lagrangian. But how can I physically see why this term does not affect the motion of the bob in this particular case? It obviously affects the potential energy (which in general affects motion of the bob) of the pendulum bob in a time varying manner - its contribution to the potential varies periodically with time.

Comment: You *shouldn't* omit the terms in the Lagrangian.

Comment: Since the first term depends only on time, it can be shown that it does not affect the extremal of the corresponding action. Alternatively, you can stick such a term into an Euler-Lagrange equation in an "off-shell" sense and show that it satisfies the equation.

Answer (score 1):

Intuitively, I can offer two hopefully helpful ways to think about a purely time-dependent term.

First, since such a term depends on neither positions nor velocities, it has no spatial gradient, so there is no corresponding force. Neither the potential nor the kinetic energy are changed if we displace the system or change its velocities. So if I may be permitted to abuse the language somewhat, it is like adding a "time-varying constant" term to the Lagrangian.

Second, insofar as the action principle is concerned, the action, that is, the difference between the kinetic and potential energy, will obviously change: however, its minimum with respect to positions and velocities will not. So once again the conclusion is that the trajectory of the system in phase space remains unaffected by such a potential.

In terms of the math, what happens is that given a generic Lagrangian in the form $L(q,\dot{q},t)=L_q(q,\dot{q},t)+L_t(t)$ (I am suppressing indices like $q_i$ but these thoughts are not limited to the case of a single degree of freedom), the corresponding Euler-Lagrange equation is

$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial q}-\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial L}{\partial\dot{q}}=\frac{\partial L_q}{\partial q}-\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial L_q}{\partial\dot{q}}=0,$$

since both $\partial L_t/\partial q=\partial L_t/\partial\dot{q}=0$, so the purely time-dependent terms drop out of the equations of motion or field equations. The same thing applies in the Hamiltonian formalism: the Hamiltonian itself acquires a purely time-dependent term, but the definition of the canonical momenta ($p=\partial L/\partial\dot{q}=\partial L_q/\partial\dot{q}$) remains the same, and the time-dependent term vanishes from the Hamiltonian equations of motion ($H=p\dot{q}-L=p\dot{q}-L_q-L_t=H_q-L_t$, $\dot{p}=-\partial H/\partial q=-\partial H_q/\partial q$, $\dot{q}=\partial H/\partial p=\partial H_q/\partial p$).

Comment: The point about the purely time-dependent term not contributing to the force is interesting. However, I wasn't able to follow the remaining few lines in the first point. Can you please elaborate on this? Looking from another angle, am I right in saying that the energy is not conserved for the pendulum bob (mass).

Comment: OK, another way of saying what I am trying to say is that purely time dependent means that the term does not depend on positions and velocities. Which means that no matter how you alter your trajectory, the term remains the same. So changing your trajectory does not change the Lagrangian through this term. And you are absolutely right, the presence of such a term means that energy is not conserved. Energy conservation is the consequence of the time translation symmetry of the Lagrangian (Noether's theorem).